# How to Enable .MP4 File Video In IIS 7.5

Tags: asp.net, iis

I want to open file video but it not working

[image: Cannot open file video]

> I'm tried enabled directory browsing.
>
> Tried run aspnet_regiis.exe -i

[image: I Check All]

## Finally

> How to open it? How to make it working? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I suggest you could add below config to set the MP4 mime map setting for your IIS web application.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".m4a" mimeType="video/mp4" />
    </staticContent>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

More details, you could refer to below article:
https://blogs.iis.net/bills/how-to-add-mime-types-with-iis7-web-config

Answer (score 2):

Hi i know is a old post but i hope that it can help you

1.- First create a folder into C:\inetpub\wwwroot example : resources

2.- Open IIS or windows + R and write inetmgr

3.- You'll see the folder you just created

[image: iis configuration]

4.- select the folder for this example "resources" and you'll see on the right all option to config

[image: directory browsing]

select and open "directory browsing" there's an option to change disabled/enable put it on enable and save changes

5.- Open browser and type the ip or url of your site and you'll see the files
[image: result config]

6.- if you can't open the file check if the MIME Types and add the format of the resource.

[image: MIME Types]

[image: adding format to open in browser]

This changes will be on Resources Folder or in the folder that you're working.

Comment: Include images in the answer please, not just the links.